# gvim/vim: launching from within Java program with parameters

Tags: java, html, vim

I'm calling vim/gvim from within a Java program to convert a source code containing file into html, as follows: `"gvim -c \"set syntax=java\" -c \"TOhtml\" -c \"wq\" -c \"q\" -c \"q\" " + Konst.FPATH + "tmp.txt"`
However, for some reason gvim thinks "syntax=java" is a name of a file, and ends up spitting out tons of messages ".syntax=java.swp" found, and more importantly does not apply syntax highlight after all. How to fix this?

EDIT: For some reason, "set syntax=java" is misinterpreted, and gvim opens a file syntax=java" -- exactly this, with a double-quote at the end.

Comment: Did you tried this command in command line?

Comment: @SibiCoder: I did, it works as it should, leaving tmp.txt.html.

Answer (score 0):

Executing an external program from Java is generally not a good idea, especially if this code run on a web server. It might lead to serious security issues.

What are you trying to do? If your goal is to highlight some Java code, just use a code highlighting library.
I don't know any Java highlighting library, but you can find some good Javascript libs ([highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/), [prismjs](http://prismjs.com/), [code-prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify), etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with "gvim  -s script.vim" command, where in script.vim I put (!) ":set syntax=java" etc -- yes, starting with ":".